# How to add a meta tag to clipboard when copying programmatically with javascript?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I am trying to programmatically insert a table into clipboard to be pasted into google spreadsheets.

Here is what I have done:

```js
$('.copy').click(function() {
 var copyContainer = $('<div>'); //a hidden container to copy from
 copyContainer.append('<meta name="generator" content="Sheets"/>');
  
 copyContainer.css('position', 'absolute').css('z-index', -999).css('opacity', 0);
 $('body').prepend(copyContainer);
 copyContainer.attr('contenteditable', true);
 
    // Let's grab a table from html to make example simpler
 copyContainer.append($('table').clone());
 copyContainer.select();
  
 copyContainer.on('focus', function() { 
  document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null) 
 });
 copyContainer.focus();
  
 document.execCommand('copy');
 copyContainer.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="copy">Copy!</button>
<table><tr><td data-sheets-note="test">123</td></tr></table>
```

The problem is that this puts the following into my clipboard:

```
<html>
<body>
<!--StartFragment-->
  <table style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;; font-size: medium; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-sheets-note="test">123</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
<!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
```

But this (the same with an added meta tag) is what I need (so the google spreadsheets would recognize it correctly and add the note to the cell):

```
<html>
<body>
<!--StartFragment-->
  <meta name="generator" content="Sheets"/>
  <table style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;; font-size: medium; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-sheets-note="test">123</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
<!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
```

How coudl I force the meta tag to be added in the clipboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can edit the clipboard data if we catch the event. It means we have to set up a listener for the `copy` event and we have to set up a global flag to know if a copy event is such that it should be tinkered with.

Well, if we're setting the clipboard contents directly, we might as well not put the elements in DOM at all and store them in another global variable instead.

Working snippet:

```js
$('.copy').click(function() {
    // Let's grab a table from html to make example simpler
 var theTable = $('table');

 copyingTable = true;
    tableToCopy = theTable [0].outerHTML; 

 document.execCommand('copy');
 copyingTable = false;
});

copyingTable = false;
document.addEventListener('copy', function(e) {
 if (copyingTable)
 {
  var data = '<meta name="generator" content="Sheets"/>' + tableToCopy;

  e.clipboardData.setData('text/html', data);
  e.preventDefault();
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="copy">Copy!</button>
<table><tr><td data-sheets-note="test">123</td></tr></table>
```